# Inlining TD Tags that Carry Divs in Them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m sort of new to coding. I made some TD tags in my table and now I need them to be inline at a browser resolution of 620px. I know that tables are so 1990s, but I think this made the most sense for me at the time that I was planning out how to code the layout. Here is a link to the page in question:

[Click here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXZRrg).

If you reduce the browser to 620px, all of the tables float to the left, which is fine, but I need every other TD tag to go to the right. I’ve tried reducing the width of the overall table, but this hasn’t worked. I’ve tried reducing the .container class and this just messes things up more. The display-inline-table combination doesn’t work very well either.

Here is a link to CodePen if you'd like to see the code in plainview:
[Click here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXZRrg).

Here is what a typical TD-tag looks like:

```
<td style="background: url('images/blog/image1.png') no-repeat; background-size: cover; " class="tablebox">
<div class="blogbackground">
<div class="blogheader">
<span class="title">Side project - Lineup app case study</span class="title">
</div>
<!-- end of blogheader -->
<div class="date">
Nov 20, 2016
</div>
<!-- end of date -->
</div>
<!-- end of blogbackground -->
</td>
```

Any help would be *super* appreciated.

Thanks so much everybody.

Sincerely,

Todd

Comment: are you sure you wanna do this with td tag only, you may thin k of using it with div, as table are not that responsive, whereas tables are

Comment: Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked (not even codepen). The above is incomplete. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. The site has a built-in Stack Snippets feature (the `<>` toolbar button). If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: I included the code that I'm concerned with in the question. People shouldn't have to read the reams of code that I have already made just to answer something that is relatively simple. I gave people the option to do so with codepen, but they don't need to.